# asp.net mvc 4 when submitting form for file upload the validation works only AFTER file has been uploaded to webserver. why?

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, form-submit, input-type-file

I want to do the validations (required fields, length validations and terms and condition check, also file size check ... before the file will be submited to webserver)

now file is uploaded to webserver and after it (for a 2GB file it takes e.g. 20 min) i get the error messages if i leave fields like 'title' empty.

How can validations be done before?

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Home")){
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Video Upload</legend>

        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new {@Class = "action add", title="Enter your video/movie title here." })
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Description)
                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new Dictionary<string,object>{{"rows","3"}})
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.AGB)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.AGB, new {@class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>

        <input type="file" id="fileCntrl" name="uploadFile" accept="video/*" data-val="true" data-val-required="File is required"/>
        <button type="submit" id="btnUpload" value="Upload Video" title="Upload Video" class="btn">Upload Video</button>

    </fieldset>
}
```

Model:

```
public class UploadModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)], ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "* Title:")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300)], ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Description:")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "* I agree to mowee.tv Terms And Conditions.")]
    public bool AGB { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public virtual ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, UploadModel myModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) // **<== i arrive here after file has been submitted to webserver**
    {
        try
        {
            if (myModel.AGB == false)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please read our Terms and Conditions");
                return View("Index", myModel);
            }

            if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //write some data to database
                //send mail with link for uploaded file
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please choose a video/movie.");
                return View("Index", myModel);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "An error occured. Try again.");
            return View("ErrorUpload", myModel);
        }

        //model is valid
        return View("SuccessUpload", myModel);
    }
    // model is not valid
    return View("Index", myModel);
}
```

Comment: That's the way HTTP works.  You need client-side validation.

Comment: i'm a newbie in asp.net. how i should handle that? do you have any useful and working solutions for me?

Comment: @SLaks Don't you mean "server-side"?

Comment: hehe. don't confuse me ;o)

Comment: Validate and save all the required information in a first step.  Then, in a second step, upload the file.

Comment: @KyleTrauberman: No (or rather, not only); server-side validation can't run until the upload finishes.

Answer (score 0):

File fields are inaccessible via JavaScript for security reasons, so client side validation won't work against them.  You'll need to perform validation on the server.

Comment: how i should do it? when submitting the form the file is already going to upload and after it i get in my controller where i do the validations. how i can do them before?

Comment: You can't.  Validation on the file field must be done on the server.

Comment: What do you mean by inaccessible. If I want to validate extension I can get the value of the file input and I get `C:\fakepath\iconnew.png `. That's definitely enough to do it.